# Temporary Cloud Objects

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I want to create cloud objects that are only available for about a day. Can I somehow automate the deletion by setting some kind of timer somewhere?

As far as I understand it, everytime I use `CloudExport[]` the resulting object stays in the cloud until I manually delete it.

Best,
Max

Comment: afaic you need at least the developer plan and run appropriate scheduled task after deployment. In case of storing expressions you could experiment with PersistentValue or Databin both of which have expiration date setting. Another way could be to deploy a `Delayed` `HTTPRedirect` object which only redirects to the source before the expiration date. Not neat and it sill is there but something to think about.

Comment: Is there an overview somewhere about the functionalities with other plans?

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/development-platform/pricing/

Comment: I can not find anything about scheduled tasks on the page you posted. Is it hidden on the page somewhere?

Comment: There's a lot of subtle differences between the plans. ScheduledTasks are one of the things that differs a lot between pricing levels. The pricing page doesn't really cover everything in detail.

Comment: But in general, this is a great suggestion. Personally, I try to put all my "temp" cloud objects in a single directory ```CloudDeploy[obj, "tempdir/example1"]```. I then always know it's safe to delete tempdir.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this, as I have not used it myself, but from the documentation for [`PersistenceLocation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PersistenceLocation.html)

```
PersistenceLocation["Cloud"];

PersistentValue["b2", PersistenceTime -> Quantity[1, "Days"]] = 55;
```

or for objects

```
ClearAll[po];

po = PersistentObject["myob", "Cloud"];

po["ExpirationDate"] = Now + Quantity[1, "Days"];

po["Value"] = 17
(* 17 *)

Through@PersistentObjects[All, "Cloud"][All]
(* {<|"HeldValue" -> Hold[17], 
  "CreationDate" -> 3.7409028803224120*10^9, "Creator" -> "Rodolfo", 
  "ModificationDate" -> 3.7409028870557971*10^9, 
  "LanguageVersion" -> 11.3, 
  "ExpirationDate" -> 3.7409892791783465*10^9, 
  "MergingFunction" -> Automatic, 
  "ValuePreprocessingFunction" -> Automatic|>} *)
```

Comment: Being experimental functionality, I would not be surprised if the PersistenceTime feature only applied to local objects - I guess I should try it out.

Comment: It works! given that it does, I'm really surprised the option PersistenceTime wasn't extended for CloudObjects in general.

Comment: @Searke I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @Searke does it work with APIs, Forms, ScheduledTasks? If it works only with values then it does not really works with `CloudObjects` but `PersistentValues`.